# Georeferencing a stack profile graph?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, dem, arcgis-pro

Is there a way to get a georeferenced profile graph from Stack Profile?

I have a DSM and use transects to get a profile graph from the DSM.
This gives an x,y value between 0 and 300m (the length of the transect).
I would like to get the profile graph in UTM.

Is this a possibility in Arc Pro?

[image][image]

Comment: If you have a 3D analyst license and your DSM is georeferenced, you can have a look at [Profile graph](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/profile-graph.htm) in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: This is the same as Stack Profile, no? It just gives you the elevation vs the horizontal distance. My DSM is georeferenced but it just returns x as the length of the profile and y the elevation

Comment: The Y axis in a Stack Profile is the elevation of the transect along your DSM, while the X-axis represents the horizontal distance of your transect(s). If you have more than one transect, they might start from different coordinates, so it's unlikely that you can plot them in the same graph. Also, as Y refers to the elevation of your DSM where it intersects the transects, and not the Y coordinates of your transect(s), your question is not clear. Please, clarify what you need (an image might help in this case).

Comment: Pictures added in the question; The first one is the DSM, the second one is derived from Stack Profile and added into Python. 
Instead of the horizontal distance ranging between 0 and 350 m, I want it to be the same coordinate system as the DSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproject the data into the coordinate reference system (CRS) of your choice.  Create the transect line in that same CRS.  [Create points along that line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-point-features-along-a-line.htm) as a new point feature class and ensure that you are creating 3d points using your surface or populate your points using [Add Surface Information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm). [Populate the attribute table with the x, y, and z coordinates](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) of your point.  Export the table into an Excel table to create the graph.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot